# High PMC counter (ILD_STALL.ANY & ILD_STALL.IQ_FULL) reported on my Intel Westmere system

Tags: performance, x86-64, intel, cpu-architecture

the PMC counters  "ILD_STALL.ANY" and "ILD_STALL.IQ_FULL"  are reporting a very high  value (i.e almost 50-60 % of cpu frequency) on my Intel Westmere based system. What could be the reason for theses stalls? I am investigating a performance issue, and suspecting these  STALLs may as well contribute to performance drop. Is there a way to bring down these stalls?